# Inspecting methods in IDEs - why aren't there side effects?

Tags: debugging, ide

Some IDEs (like Eclipse) seem to allow method calls to be inspected while debugging. How is this done without causing side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in Visual Studio, executing code as part of 'inspecting' some value can indeed have effects.  I think all debuggers are probably like this.  Beware!

Comment: yes, that's the point of calling the function... the sideeffects!

Comment: I found a blog post claiming [Func-eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/03/23/400794.aspx) with a [whole category](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/category/11475.aspx) about this

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19299/brian) is [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688017/inspecting-methods-in-ides-why-arent-there-side-effects/2688029#2688029). However, you **could** do it by saving the registers and tracking any memory writes, and restoring them when the inspection ends